# My React Router Links are not working. It's showing the url change in the browser but contents are not showing

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

My folder structure

```
reactdemo
|------------>public
|------------>src
               |------->Component
               |------->index.js
```

<-------------index.js------------>

```
import React from 'react';

import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './Component/Header';
import Footer from './Component/Footer';
import Content from './Component/Content';
import About from './Component/about';
import Contact from './Component/Contact';
import JSON from  './Component/db.json';





class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        items:JSON
    }


   render() {
  //    console.log(this.state.items)
      return (
         <div>
            <Header/>
            <Content list={this.state.items} />
            <Footer />

         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

<---------Header Component------------->

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//Component

import About from './about.js';
import Contact from './Contact.js';


class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
 <Router>    
<div>
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">




              <ul className="navbar-nav">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                 </li>
              </ul>
  </nav>

  <Switch>
  <Route path='/About' Component={About} />     
  <Route path='/Contact' Component={Contact} />
  </Switch>

</div>
</Router>
  );
}
}



export default Header;
```

<----------Content---------------->

```
import React from 'react';

const Content =(props) => {

console.log(props)


  const test = props.list.map((list) => {
    return (
        <div key={list.id}>
        <h4>{list.title}</h4>
        <p>{list.feed}</p>
      </div>
      )

    }
  )


 return (
    <div>
    {test}
    </div>
  )



}

export default Content;
```

<---------footer.js---------->

```
   import React from 'react';

class Footer extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="text-center">

  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  someone@example.com</a>.</p>

        </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Footer;
```

<---------about---------->

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class About extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export default About;
```

<------------Contact---------->

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Contact extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export default Contact;
```

<-----------End of Code-------->

I'm new to react and trying to implement react router. But I'm facing an issue- whenever I click on About and Contact link, the url changes in the browser, but the contents don't show in the browser. I have created separate contents for both "about" and "contact" inside the Components folder.Also, I'm using Sublime text 3 and using Babel for ES-6 as plugin but it's showing syntax error.I have also attached a screenshot for showing the issue

[image]

Comment: Can you show the snapshot of the error

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Hello Subham....I have attached the screen shot. As you can see that...when I click on the "about" link, the content is not changing in the browser but in the url it's showing the changes.

Comment: if you got the answer, then accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Link` paths are defined as `/about` and `/contact`, where the `Route` paths are `/About` and `/Contact`, notice the **uppercase** first character and hence it doesn't match, also Route accepts a lower case `component` prop and not `Component`

```
<Router>    
     <div>
         <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
              <ul className="navbar-nav">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                 </li>
              </ul>
         </nav>
         <Switch>
             <Route path='/about' component={About} />     
             <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
         </Switch>

     </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

You write your component attribute with first letter uppercase, so `Component` should be `component`:

So instead of:

```
<Route path='/About' Component={About} /> 
<Route path='/Contact' Component={Contact} />
```

You should have:

```
<Route path='/About' component={About} /> 
<Route path='/Contact' component={Contact} />
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//Component

import About from './about.js';
import Contact from './Contact.js';


class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
 <Router>    
<div>
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
              <ul className="navbar-nav">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                     <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                 </li>
              </ul>
  </nav>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/About' component={About} /> 
    <Route path='/Contact' component={Contact} />
  </Switch>

</div>
</Router>
  );
}
}



export default Header;
```

It's not a deal breaker to use the `path` prop value to uppercase, because it's not case sensitive by default, but is recommended to have the `<Route>` path props the same you define on the `<Link>`, in case you have a prop like `sensitive` defined on the `<Route>` element.

In this case your final piece of code should look like this:

```
<Route path='/about' component={About} /> 
<Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
```

You can read more about this in the docs **[here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)**.